# laravel filter relation condition whereHas and with function have problems

Tags: laravel

This is my code:

```
public function getInvoiceOfTransactioncCompleteItems($userid)
{
  return $user_invoice = 
    $this->model->with([
      'items.itemStatus' => function($q) {
        $q->where('item_statuses_id', '=', '12');
      },
      'items',
      'items.product',
      'items.product.user',
      'items.rating',
      'items.rating_comment'
    ])
    ->where('user_id',$userid)
    ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
    ->paginate(3);
}
```

I want it give me just ( with(['items.itemStatus'=>function($q){
            $q->where('item_statuses_id','=','12');

but it give me all stuff but items.itemStatus column array are empty except item_statuses_id','=','12'

i dont want other item ,just want item_statuses_id','=','12'  item

my json

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1o_V0MRu1somd3rMuzaCtvVY5twhrIBHYfD_N2Fhw9O8/edit?usp=sharing

my code
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YadZmU0Q_OO5himc8JUsFT6vUcZmG4A3D3OjmsG5VdY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I want my json be 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nYKXav7qriJnLIkutmETRmn519lJanwYVdJqTyjuSFw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Consider using a join and write a where condition on the main query instead of using with

Comment: I trying,  but confuse,why  with or whereHas cant do it

Comment: I've written my comment as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said:

> I trying, but confuse,why with or whereHas cant do it

I am not 100% sure, but I think when you place a condition on `with()` you are modifying a **sub query** rather than placing a condition on the **main query** - does that make sense?

If you would like to get a better idea, please try debugging your query by running `toSql()` on your query to get a better idea of what is going on...

```
$this->model->with([
    'items.itemStatus' => function($q) {
        $q->where('item_statuses_id', '=', '12');
        },
        'items',
        'items.product',
        'items.product.user',
        'items.rating',
        'items.rating_comment'
    ])
    ->where('user_id',$userid)
    ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
    ->toSql();
```

then take a look at the SQL output.

Answer (score 0):

```
I try other method

query order table
user->invoice
invoice ->item
item->itemStatus   condition status =12
get itemStatus 's item id
Item::with('invoice')->whereIn([])

but how can I reverse

it will be 
{
item_id,
invoice:{invoice_id:1}
}
I want be 
{
invoice_id,
items:[{item_id:1,item_id:2}]
}
and invoice same will merge
```